# matching two lists of words and return the matched words

Tags: r, match

I want to loop through a list of string to another list

```
cutter_Ch <- c('happy','birthday','Lucia') 
pos <- c('Lucia','today')
```

one way I can do it is with lapply

```
pos.matches = lapply(cutter_Ch, pmatch, pos)

[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] 1
```

However, I want the function return the matched string instead of NA and number of times matched, like this

```
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] Lucia
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use the index to subset the 'pos'

```
lapply(cutter_Ch, function(x) pos[pmatch(x, pos)])
```

---

It is not clear whether this example is simplified version of something more complex.  Anyway, with `str_extract` we can get the same output in a `vector`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(cutter_Ch, paste(pos, collapse="|"))
#[1] NA      NA      "Lucia"
```